# How to deserialize geolocation point data to a Java entity?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, geolocation

I am trying to deserialize a point into a java object.

Here is the entity class I am using.

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.*;



@Data
@Entity(name = "magic_points")
public class MagicPoint {
    @Id
    Integer id;

    @Column(name = "p", columnDefinition="Point")
    private Point point;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}
```

The repository

```
import com.playground.springplayground.db.entities.MagicPoint;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

public interface MagicPointRepository extends Repository<MagicPoint, Integer> {

    List<MagicPoint> getAllByDescription(String description);
}
```

And the way how I am calling it.

```
        List<MagicPoint> magicPoints = magicPointRepository.getAllByDescription("Abc");
```

I am using the following library for geodata:

> compile group: 'com.vividsolutions', name: 'jts', version: '1.13'

Database is a MySql, Ver 8.0.13

And the data I stored in Database:

[image]

This is the error I am receiving:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: E6100000
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Is com.vividsolutions.jts is a good approach for mapping geodata stored in SQL databases? 
Is it something I am missing? 
I couldn't find anything related to this until now. The mapping error message doesn't bring any useful information if there is a driver missing or some other dependency I should consider.

**EDIT**
In order to reproduce it on your local machine I added the code on Github

```
git clone https://github.com/florin-t/deserialize-geolocation-point.git
```

There is also a README.TXT with some instructions regarding the Database and application.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the mysql dialect to `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56InnoDBSpatialDialect`
eg. `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56InnoDBSpatialDialect`

also make sure you do not have incompatibilities with the hibernate library (if you use hibernate-spatial 5.2.5.Final you project works)

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadoc of [`Repository<T, ID>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html)
the meaning of `ID` is the following:

> `ID` - the type of the id of the entity the repository manages

In your entity `MagicPoint` the `id` has type `Integer`.
Therefore you need to declare your repository as

```
public interface MagicPointRepository extends Repository<MagicPoint, Integer>
```

instead of as

```
public interface MagicPointRepository extends Repository<MagicPoint, Point>
```

Comment: Indeed is a small mistake there, However after changing it I still have exactly the same error message.

Comment: I also added the whole code on github if you have time to check it on your local machine.